# S0-2 (S2) Diameter/Radius

Tags: observational-astronomy, star, radio-astronomy, milky-way, sagittarius-a

I'm a student, I am doing an investigation about [S0-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2_(star)). My idea was to take the wavelength that emanates from the star.

When I saw the data from [Science magazine](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aav8137) I found a problem that was that the data I got is the wavelength that reaches us, which gave me the idea of ​​taking the frequency of the wave that emanates from S0-2, but in order to do this I needed data that I am missing. This data is the radius of the star, using [this formula](https://www3.gobiernodecanarias.org/medusa/ecoblog/mramrodp/?p=696)
$$V=-G\frac{M}{r}$$

I can get the gravitational potential of S0-2.

Please, If anyone knows the diameter or radius of S0-2, I´d be thankful if you share it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S2 is a massive main sequence star, with a spectral type between B0V and B2V (according to [Paumard et.al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0601268))  Such stars have mass that is between than 8 and 18 times that of the sun and a radius that is between 5 and 8 times the radius of the sun.  The exact spectral type (and hence the size) is not known for certain due to the difficulty in observing stars through the dust and nebulae near the centre of the galaxy.